# Django - Sending email with sendgrid templates - problem with a from address

Tags: django, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am using Sendgrid Dynamic Transactional Templates to send emails from my django project. The code can be seen below.

```
sg = SendGridAPIClient(djangoSettings.SENDGRID_KEY)
    message = Mail(
            from_email = some@email,
            to_emails=some@email,
    )
    message.dynamic_template_data = {...
            }

    message.template_id = '....'

    response = sg.send(message)
```

The email sends fine, but I need to use a from_email to send. I don't want to use an email they can reply to. I want some generic email associated with my sendgrid account, lets say mydomain.com. How can I go about solving that?

Comment: what the error code  / message ?

Comment: if I use a real email, there is no error code. If I do not include a from_mail, the error is  response = self.client.mail.send.post(request_body=message.get()) return Response(self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout))

Comment: To add more details, my site has a messaging app between users. I am trying to send an email notification to the user when he gets a new message. That is why I do not want to use a real email in the from_email

Comment: have to set "mail from" from your sendgrid account option ?. i never using sendgrid and usually smtp provider need set yourself "mail_from" manual on smtp account option dashboard then you can use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have authorized the domain in your Sendgrid account you can add any address you want so long as it's part of the authorized domain.

To do this go to, https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/sender_auth, press **Authenticate your domain** and follow the steps to add your domain. This includes configuring your DNS, DKIM and SPF. For more details on adding a domain visit [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication/)

Now in your code, you could add `noreply@yourdomain.com`, or any variation of that, as the from address so long as you authenticated `yourdomain.com`.